# Proving closure under addition for $\mathbb{Q}$ by assuming fraction multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under addition. What I did:

> $\mathbb{Q}$ is defined as the set of numbers such that $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{I}$ (integers) and $q\ne 0$. 
>   Let $a=\frac{p_1}{q_1},b=\frac{p_2}{q_2}$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, then
>   $$
> a+b=\frac{p_1}{q_1}+\frac{p_2}{q_2}=\frac{p_1}{q_1}(q_2/q_2)+\frac{p_2}{q_2}(q_1/q_1) \tag{1}
> $$
>   $$
> \Rightarrow a+b=\frac{p_1q_2+p_2q_1}{q_1q_2} \tag{2}
> $$
>   If, $\alpha=p_1q_2+p_2q_1, \beta=q_1q_2$, where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{I}$, therefore
>   $$
> \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\in\mathbb{Q} 
> $$

My question: I did not have to prove that multiplication in $\mathbb{Q}$ is well defined from $(1)$ to $(2)$. Is that a problem? Should a prove it first?

Comment: What is your definition of $\Bbb{Q}$? In the usual construction from $\Bbb{Z}$ the multiplications take place in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because you haven't told us what you are assuming about the rational numbers. Are you defining them to be the field of fractions of the ring of integers $\mathbb Z$? Or are you instead defining them to be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ containing $1$? Or something else?

Comment: I would say: $\mathbb{Q}$ is defined as the set of numbers such that $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{I}$ and $q\ne 0$.

Comment: What is your definition of addition on $\Bbb Q$? You seem to find $\frac{p_1q_1+p_2q_2}{q_1q_2}$ as a consequence rather than a definition. The things to heck out here are in particular that this addition is well-defined and that the constructed denominator is non-zero.

Comment: How is that a number? It is not. It's an equivalence class of pairs of integers, rather.

Comment: So if by $\mathbb I$ you mean "the integers", then the next question is, what do you mean by $\frac{p}{q}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that $\frac{p_1}{q_1} + \frac{p_2}{q_2} =\frac{p_1q_2+p_2q_1}{q_1q_2}$ is the *definition* of the addition in $\Bbb Q$; we only need that $\Bbb I$ is a commutative ring without zero-divisors for that to work. You only need to check well-definedness (wrt the equivalence relation, so replacing $\frac{p_1}{q_1}$ by the equivalent $\frac{kp_1}{kq_1}$ gives an equivalent sum too) but that is rather easy.